# Dispute harsh review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit, first-questions

I understand this is a duplicate question with questionable quality, but I think using this as a test is fairly unfair. The following things tripped me up:

- Use of formatting (headings and bullet points)
- Examples of what the user was looking for
- First comment seemed to understand the question
- The question had an answer, so somebody understood the question enough to answer

The question has been taken down, but here is the link to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71874349) (visible to 10k+ users) and here is the link to the [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31664634) (visible to all).

Whether you think I'm right or wrong, please let me know how you would review this.

[image: Image of dispute]

Comment: What decision did you make? I can see many problems with the post right off the bat. Did you click to edit it? That would be completely understandable.

Comment: They selected **Looks OK**, according to the review link.

Comment: Re *"The question had an answer, so somebody understood the question enough to answer"*: Well, sometimes [psychic skillz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47906/etiquette-for-dealing-with-hint-answers/47911#47911) are applied.

Comment: This is not a good question; it shows absolutely zero prior effort on the OP's part.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine This is my first question on the site, I put effort into creating a discussion that would improve my auditing skills. Do you have anything constructive to add?

Comment: @ZachJensz I didn't mean your question, I meant the one you referred to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let me start by saying I don't particularly like **Duplicate** review audits. Excepting basic questions, they can be easy to miss if you aren't a subject matter expert. Note that using tag filters can help by providing reviews for tags you are interested in, although audits from other tags can be slipped in so watch out for those.

That said, this question revolves around regex which are among the most asked questions on the site. Most of those have been asked before for most regex engines so I would have at least searched for a dupe target on my own for this one. That said, you don't *have* to choose **Looks OK** if you don't see a problem. **Skip** is an option and should be used on posts you aren't confident in judging (not that you should have in this case, I don't know your personal expertise). Interacting with the post in other ways, such as commenting, voting on a comment, or voting on the post itself enables the **Other Action** option as well.

In the case of this question there are other problems with it aside from its duplicate status. The user was essentially asking for code (in the form of a regex pattern) with no shown attempt, and gave examples for the desired behavior. Upvoting the comment by the user asking for OP to provide their code or providing your own comment would have enabled the **Other Action** selection. Downvoting also would have done this.

**Edit** would have also been a good action to add some formatting to what OP provided, particularly with the example output they requested. Even though the question was in bad form, we can still make it *read* better.

Comment: Selecting "looks ok" on a question that is already deleted is troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bender the Greatest. I use the other action option a lot actually, but I take it you're suggesting to only use the looks ok option if the question has no issues whatsoever.

Comment: There is also the greeting "Good day" at the start which definitely needs to be removed.

Comment: @ZachJensz - There are numerous meta questions on when selecting “looks ok” is justified